# How to optimize between select for timestamps

Tags: performance, postgresql

I have a timestamp field in my Table and want to select

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE time BETWEEN '2014-12-06' AND '2014-12-09'
```

i've create this index

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON table (time);
```

the table has 1.014.890 entries

the query returns 282.000 records in 16secs

EXPLAIN

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on trackdatagps  (cost=6126.29..25884.11 rows=288188 width=79)"
"  Recheck Cond: (("time" >= '2014-12-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) 
                  AND 
                  ("time" <= '2014-12-09 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table  (cost=0.00..6054.24 rows=288188 width=0)"
"        Index Cond: (("time" >= '2014-12-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) 
                      AND 
                      ("time" <= '2014-12-09 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
```

is there a way to speed this up? i think 16secs are too long

Comment: what is the duration if you just query for `count(*)` i.e. how much of that time is due to latency passing 282k rows to the caller?

Comment: It's returning 17625 records per second, not that bad. Did you check EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see how much time is spend in executing the query? I think most time is spent in returning the data, not in executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
cluster table using myindex;
```

that will run slow (especially the first time) but it will organise the table content to make the query you use more efficient.

especially if you use smaller time ranges or have a bigger table.